# Specific scene / Dialogue / quote tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This question is about two tags - [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) and [quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) (and to a lesser extent [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene)).

Dialogue is defined as: *Questions related to specific pieces of a work's spoken word.*

Quote is: *A brief excerpt from a character's lines in a movie for question emphasis or analysis*

Are both of these tags necessary? I can see why dialogue is difference from a quote, but looking through question histories it seems that often they've been used interchangeably (often paired with [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) as well).

I'm basically seeing do we want to do anything about this, or simply make it clearer.

For example, if a question is about a specific line in the film, is that [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene)? Or is that [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) and [quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote)? If a question is about the meaning of several lines, is that [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) and [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue)?

What would people consider the proper use of all of these, as currently I feel, looking at all the [dialogue questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue), [the quote questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) and [the specific scene questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene), there is a bit of confusion and lack of consistency over this.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that they have been used a bit confusingly, especially as of recent.

I could see how [quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) has some specific meaning compared to the more general [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue), i.e. when used for a specific characteristic line and especially in contexts other than mere explanation, like [reference](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference)-style questions or [origin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) questions. However, in the majority of cases the difference to [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) is quite muddled and its hard to assess when something is a singular quote conpared to more complex dialogue, and especially in the context of `dialogue-explanation` type questions I would prefer [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) over [quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) anyway.

**I would thus propose to make [quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) a synonym of [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue).**

I would, however, not interfere this further with [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene), which to me is rather orthogonal to both [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) and [quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote). Well, the usage of [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) is a bit confusing in itself (afterall, many questions are about a specific scene), but all in all [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) has its uses, I guess. But I would treat the (dis)advantages of [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) separately from the [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) problem. I am personally not a particularly big fan of using [specific-scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-scene) for `dialogue-explanation` questions, but haven't ever seen it as too big a problem to warrant retagging, though.

Comment: +1. I could go with this. I do think specific scene is a tad confusing at times, but it certainly has its uses. It would be nice to get some consent on this, as currently I leave these three tags alone when doing most of my question-editing, as they've been so interchangeable. Joining quote and dialogue would be a big step in the right direction though, in my view.

Comment: So we are doing it or not?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I just wanted to give people some more consideration time after I `featured` it, maybe a few days.

Comment: ok fair enough.